# One function building SQL-strings by parameters. A security risk?

Tags: sql, security

I try to avoid writing the SQL-code for each and every update or insert. Instead a PHP-function takes some parameters (add or change, tablename, fields-list) and builds the SQL from it. This is similar, but not identical, to the preferred method of using parameterized statements (mysqli).

Is my way of creating SQL putting a big smile in the face of hackers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh yes - see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection), and the obligatory [xkcd reference](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 1):

It's only a security risk if you allow any user input to get added to the SQL queries. You are fine if you are using constant parameters defined in your source code, but the actual values coming from users of your website should always be using bound parameters and never added directly to the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a security risk unless you can devote significant resources to testing your function for abuse/misuse.

There are other factors that you should consider. Building dynamic SQL reduces the ability of the database to cache queries - each time you call your function, your query will be parsed as a new one. This might have a significant impact on performance. Using bind parameters doesn't impose the same problem as the database can recognize the parameters as the variable part of the query.